# Which one is better? Fetch NSArray and search in there, or fetch one object at a time from Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to update an entity based on data coming from a web server.
I get an array of objects from the server and these objects each have an ID which is also stored as a field in the entity.
For each object in the data from the server I search (perform a fetch request for one object) for the corresponding NSManagedObject in Core Data and update/save it.

I was wondering if it would be better to fetch an NSArray of NSManagedObjects instead and then use an NSPredicate to search for the NSManagedObject with matching ID in the NSArray (which is in memory).

Is this correct and will the improvements be significant?

Is there maybe a better way to handle such update?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Iterate over batches of ids fetching only the instances for that batch and update them in a loop. Test to optimise the batch size (perhaps start at 100, use the core data instrument to check performance). It's a trade off between memory usage and speed.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your second solution. You create a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entityID IN %@", fetchedIDsFromWeb]
```

Keep in mind that Core Data has many optimisations built in so that even if you fetch lots of records it would still not necessarily be too much of a strain on memory.

Batching could be useful, either if memory becomes tight or if you can somehow exploit the latency of the records coming in through the web. If the fetch takes too long it might be enough to set a suitable `fetchBatchSize` for your fetch request.